# The most efficient way to store a very large 2D array in Python/MicroPython

Tags: python, arrays, embedded, micropython

I have a project in an embedded system (NodeMCU running MicroPython), where I need to store a very large array of variables, which have values of either 0 or 1. I need to be able to read/write them individually or via loops in a convenient way. For this example, I am filling the array with random integers between 0 and 1:

```
N = 50
table = [[randInt(0,1) for i in range(N)] for j in range(N)]
```

On my NodeMCU, even such a small array (2500 items) is enough to exceed the NodeMCU memory limits, crashing my script. I suppose this is because that in Python, int is an object with a lot of overhead. Since in my case I do not need the capacity of int variable - actually, 0 or 1 could be stored as a bit - how can I create and fill an array with the least-memory-consuming variables? Say, like in this example, randomizing between 0 and 1. I reviewed the [uctypes](https://www.sutron.com/micropython/html/library/uctypes.html), but as I'm new to Python, I couldn't get these to work. Or is there another way? How can create such an array with the least memory usage possible?

Comment: try with 'T' or 'F'

Comment: You can use each bit as separate value. which will help you to store 8 times more data. If it still not enough, you should use file buffer.

Comment: How do I use T or F?
@OlvinRoght, I read that in Python, int takes 3 bytes, right? So shouldn't I be able to store 3*8 = 24 times more data?

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas, in python int has no fixed size, but if you'll use `array.array` with `'B'`, each element of this array will consume 1 byte.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification, @OlvinRoght. I will try to find a way to store this data as bits.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `bytearray` to store the data. You can store 8 bits per byte by calculating the index
for the byte and the bit in that byte that corresponds to a particular row and column. Once you have
the indexes you can use bit shifts and bitwise operators to set, clear or retrieve the value for
that row and column.

```py
class bitarray2d():
    """create 2d array of bits cols wide and rows high"""
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.bits = bytearray(cols * rows >> 3)
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows

    def set(self, column, row):
        """set the bit that corresponds to the column and row given"""
        bit = (row * self.cols) + column
        self.bits[bit >> 3] |= 1 << 7 - (bit % 8)

    def clear(self, column, row):
        """clear the bit that corresponds to the column and row given"""
        bit = (row * self.cols) + column
        self.bits[bit >> 3] &= ~(1 << 7 - (bit % 8))

    def get(self, column, row):
        """get the value of the bit that corresponds to the column and row given"""
        bit = (row * self.cols) + column
        return 1 if self.bits[bit >> 3] & 1 << 7 - (bit % 8) else 0

    def print(self):
        """print the bitarray as a 2d array"""
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.cols):
                print(self.get(column, row), end="")
            print()

    def line(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        """draw a line starting at x0, y0 and ending at x1, y1"""
        steep = abs(y1 - y0) > abs(x1 - x0)
        if steep:
            x0, y0 = y0, x0
            x1, y1 = y1, x1
        if x0 > x1:
            x0, x1 = x1, x0
            y0, y1 = y1, y0
        dx = x1 - x0
        dy = abs(y1 - y0)
        err = dx >> 1
        ystep = 1 if y0 < y1 else -1
        while x0 <= x1:
            if steep:
                self.set(y0, x0)
            else:
                self.set(x0, y0)
            err -= dy
            if err < 0:
                y0 += ystep
                err += dx
            x0 += 1

# Test routine
columns = 64
rows = 64

bits = bitarray2d(columns, rows)
bits.line(0, 0, columns-1, rows-1)
bits.line(columns-1, 0, 0, rows-1)
bits.print()
```

Comment: You should fix a bug in the method `clear(...)`. Otherwise it looks OK.

Comment: Thanks, left out the negate before anding.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that `int` objects have a lot of overhead. However, in this case, these `int` objects may actually be cached (in CPython they would be), so the only overhead *should* be just the pointer...

However, a pointer will still require a machine word, to not rely on such things (implementation details) and to pack things more tightly, you could use **actual arrays**, you are currently using a `list` of `list` objects.

The `arrays` module provides object-oriented wrappers around primitive, C-like numeric arrays. Unfortunately, they do not provide multidimensional arrays.

So you could try something like:

```
import array
import random

N = 50

def build_table(N):
    rng = range(N)
    result = []
    for _ in rng:
        arr = array.array('B') #unsigned byte
        for _ in rng:
            arr.append(random.randint(0,1))
        result.append(arr)
    return result

table = build_table(N)
```

If this were CPython, I would suggest the [`bitarray`](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) module for maximum efficiency. I have no idea if that is available for micropython, but you could implement something like that yourself, likely on top of an `array.array`. There are many examples of this, it is sort of a classic data structure from the times when memory was measured in bytes. [Here's](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays) just one example from the Python wiki.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and this code example. Are you sure it is correct? I get a "name 'B' isn't defined" error.

Comment: Okay, that works now, but I still don't get it... Shouldn't it produce a 2D array? When I print the "table", console prints: [array('B', [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])]

Comment: Oh, right! I am still getting the hang of Python indentations, didn't notice that one. Alright, this is now much better. But still, I am using a byte to store just 0 or 1. Is it possible to use a bit instead? I can't find bit as a datatype that array() could take as an argument.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas no, as I stated, there is a [bitarray library](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) available available for CPython, but I don't know if it will work with micropython, I doubt it though. You could implement your own on top of an `array.array`, though. depending on the complexity o you task, this is relatively achievable, and there's probably lots of guides out there since this is sort of a classic data structure. EDIT: The [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays) even has a basic implementation

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, you should know that the answer will work on Micropython.

Comment: @Patrick are you asying `array` isn't available in Micropython?

Comment: Hi @juanpa.arrivillaga in your answer you say you don't know if this will work in Micropython. A good answer would not be "maybe this will work" it would not leave that open to the reader to figure out. As is, your answer is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Patrick the answer I posted in the question *does* work in Micropython, and does decrease the memory requirements. I said if the OP wants to go even further, they'd need to us a bitarray.

Comment: I suggest deleting the part at the end then